# using pysbd as a spaCy pipeline component

Tags: python, spacy-3

I am new to spacy but I am trying to use pysbd as a spaCy pipeline component, as shown [here](https://pypi.org/project/pysbd/)

Below is the code

```
import spacy
from pysbd.utils import PySBDFactory

nlp = spacy.blank('en')

# explicitly adding component to pipeline
# (recommended - makes it more readable to tell what's going on)
nlp.add_pipe(PySBDFactory(nlp))

# or you can use it implicitly with keyword
# pysbd = nlp.create_pipe('pysbd')
# nlp.add_pipe(pysbd)

doc = nlp('My name is Jonas E. Smith. Please turn to p. 55.')
print(list(doc.sents))

#this should be the output
# [My name is Jonas E. Smith., Please turn to p. 55.]
```

when I run it I get this error

```
ValueError: [E966] `nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component. Expected string, but got <pysbd.utils.PySBDFactory object at 0x000001BA35725570> (name: 'None').

- If you created your component with `nlp.create_pipe('name')`: remove nlp.create_pipe and call `nlp.add_pipe('name')` instead.

- If you passed in a component like `TextCategorizer()`: call `nlp.add_pipe` with the string name instead, e.g. `nlp.add_pipe('textcat')`.

- If you're using a custom component: Add the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components / factories) to your custom component and assign it a name, e.g. `@Language.component('your_name')`. You can then run `nlp.add_pipe('your_name')` to add it to the pipeline.
```

SpaCy version = 3.43

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: This component and code example is only compatible with spacy v2.x, not v3.x. See a solution here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/10207#issuecomment-1030049888

Comment: @aab this woks well! Much appreciated!